# PHP inserting parsed values from text file into MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, file, text, import

I'm new to PHP and am trying to parse certain text from a txt file, and then insert the text into a MySQL database. So, let's get more specific. The file's format is as such, and it is  repeated through the document end. the ellipses represent the previous and next tones.

```
...

[Tone27]                            
Atone = 707.3                        
Btone = 746.8                        
Btonelength = 3                        
Btonedebounce = 1                    
Description = Fire Department 1                
mp3_Emails = email@address.com,email2@address.com,email3@address.com          
amr_Emails = email2@textmessaging.com,email1@textmessaging.com        
alert_command = c:\test.bat                
post_email_command = c:\test2.bat            
radio_frequency = 154.475    
exclude_from = 13:25                        
exclude_to = 13:35                        
exclude_emails = email2@textmessaging.com,email2@address.com

...
```

What I want to do is parse the first items(e.g. '[tone27]') in each "tone block" from the file and insert it into the first field of a NEW row in the db. I then need to evaluate what comes before each line's " = ", for instance "Atone," and insert what comes after that line's " = ", for instance "707.3" into a field by that name. so, this row may look like this in the db:

```
$id | [tone27] | 707.3 |746.8 | 3 | 1 | Fire Department 1 |email1@x.com,email2@x.com,e...|...
```

and so on...

i've been able to isolate each thing by performing string functions, but am unsure of how to set up a loop that would insert each value properly. Here's the code I used to isolate them, but it's not helping at all with actually getting them into the database.

```
$txt_file    = file_get_contents('config/tones.txt');
$rows        = explode("\n", $txt_file);
foreach($rows as $row => $data)
{   
$row_data = explode(' = ', $data);

if ((isset($row_data[0])) && ($row_data[0] !== " " )){
    $info[$row]['attribute'] = $row_data[0];
    $info_attribute = trim($info[$row]['attribute']);
}
if (isset($row_data[1])){
    $info[$row]['value']         = $row_data[1];
    $info_value = trim($info[$row]['value']);
    //display data
    echo 'Row ' . $row . ' Attribute: ' . $info_attribute . '<br />';
    echo 'Row ' . $row . ' Value: ' . $info_value . '<br />';
} elseif (($info[$row]['attribute']) && (!empty($info_attribute))) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo 'Row ' . $row . ' Attribute: ' . $info_attribute . '<br />';
    continue;
}
```

I'M A NOOB, NO DOUBT. I'M LOST. Thanks in advance for your help!!!

```
****|| EDIT ||****
```

Thanks for all of the excellent answers! here's what I've resultingly come up with. No queries yet, just a simple dash of the read portion of CRUD, but the code will be the same, only with queries. A big thanks to @leepowers for introducing me to the wonderful parse_ini_file() function.

```
foreach(parse_ini_file("config/tones.txt", true) as $k => $v){
extract($v, EXTR_SKIP);
echo "<br>";
echo $k . "<br>"; 
foreach($v as $sv => $ssv){ 

    $lcase_sv = strtolower($sv); 
    if (trim($lcase_sv) == 'amr_emails'){ 
        echo "sv: amr_Emails:<br>"; 
        echo "ssv:<br>";
        $eA = explode(',', trim($ssv));
        foreach($eA as $eK => $eV){ 
            echo "email" . filter_var($eK + 1, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) . ": " . $eV . "<br>"; 
        }
    } elseif (trim($lcase_sv) == 'mp3_emails'){ 
        echo "ssv:<br>";
        $eA = explode(',', trim($ssv));
        foreach($eA as $eK => $eV){
            echo "email" . filter_var($eK + 1, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) . ": " . $eV . "<br>";
        }
    }else {
        echo "sv: " . $sv .", " . "s: " . $ssv . "<br>"; 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Todd, welcome to SO. Where's your connection to the database?

Comment: Hi, @Steve. The db connection's at the top of the document. I used "require_once('db.php');" which references a db connection.

Comment: We'll need to see the code where you try to insert the values...this just stores them in an array, yes?  Everything looks pretty good so far though.

Comment: Thanks, @Steve. I haven't written a query for the task yet, because I'm not sure I'm isolating the variables in the most efficient, most usable way. Also, I am unsure of what query would be needed. I did include above what my desired db structure would be. I'll edit, putting that segment in the SO code format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`parse_ini_file`](https://www.php.net/parse_ini_file) to load the data structure into an array.

From there you can build and execute SQL statements:

```
$entries = parse_ini_file("config/tones.txt", true);
foreach ($entries as $section => $fields) {
  extract($fields, EXTR_SKIP);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (section, atone, btone) VALUES ($section, '$Atone', '$Btone'";
   ....
}
```

Of course, you'll need to prepare and escape the SQL statement before executing it.

Comment: could I just use $query = mysql_real_escape_string($sql)

Comment: I've taken the procedural route on this one! Thanks for enlightening me of the parse_ini_file() function. BRILLIANT. I've edited my question to include what I've done so far. ATM, it's just a simple read portion of CRUD. @leepowers

Answer (score 0):

[parse_ini_file($source);](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-ini-file.php) return an associative array

```
$query = 'INSET INTO ... (key, value) VALUES (:key, :value)';
$stmt  = DB::prepare($query);

foreach( parse_ini_file($source) as $key => $value )
{
  $stmt->execute(array(':key' => $key, ':source' => $source));
}
```

This example use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)

Just output of file in loop is:

```
foreach( parse_ini_file($source) as $key => $value )
{
  echo $key; // Atone in first loop
  echo $value; //707.3 in first loop

  // BUT NOT USE THIS!!! use mysqli or PDO
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO ... (key, value) VALUES ($key, $value)");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer very well, as I'm not very(or hardly at all) familiar with OOP. how could I apply this code to accomplish what I've stated above? Thanks for your help!

Comment: very helpful! However, i found that parse_ini_file() returns a multidimensional array, so this loop would actually echo "toneX" and all of its attributes as the single value. it was just a matter of embedding additional foreach loops. Thank you! @Nikita

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it. Just need to modify it according to you needs (number of rows/credentials). It's better to use PDO.

```
$username = 'yourusername';
$password = 'yourpass';

try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=yourdbname', $username, $pass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo 'successfully connected';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

foreach(parse_ini_file('yourfile.ini', true) as $row)
{
    try {
        // just adjust the number of columns accordingly
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('insert into tablename values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
        // $row contains the values to insert
        $stmt->execute($row);
        echo 'rows affected' . $stmt->rowCount(); // 1      
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man. This is great! I've edited my question to include what I've come up with so far. @Ardy